# Investigating memory leak - Commited memory grows - Heap is fine

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, windbg

I'm investigating a possible memory leak in our C#/WPF/.NET 4.51 application.

I took snapshots of the application directly after starting and after a few hours when the allocated memory grew over the top.

I checked the managed heap instances with VisualStudio's process dump tool. Everything looked perfectly fine.

Opening the dumps in WinDbg seems to confirm this, since heap and stack are growing in a way I expected it (+50MB) (left: First dump, right: Last dump):
[image: WinDbg Heap/Stack]

What irritates me, is that the size of the commited pages grew a lot (left: First dump, right: Last dump):
[image: WinDbg State summary]

Also, VMMap shows this huge commited block as 'private data' (not related to the dumps above. The screenshot has been taken about an hour later):
[image: VMMap image]

Please correct me:
Because of the fact that the heap is fine and the private bytes are directly allocated with VirtualAlloc() I can exclude 'our' managed application code from the list of possible leak candidates.

Is there a way to narrow down the cause of the leak?

Comment: Are you using any unmanaged libraries? [debugdiag 2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924) is a good place to start

Comment: If you use things like excel interpolation if you dont free all the multitudes of excel parts, it can take a very long time for the garbage collector to get round to free things.

Comment: Yes, we're using quite a few external components. I'm trying to narrow the leak a bit down before deactivating each component.  
Thanks. Trying DebugDiag right now...

Comment: which windows version? In Windows 10 1607, use ReferenceSet tracing with WPT/WPR: https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2016/06/26/new-beta-of-windows-performance-toolkit/ and look at the VAlloc callstacks to see where the memory is allocated.

Comment: Perhaps WPA could help you narrow it down. I would give [xperf - Collect Heap_Launch.cmd](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-50-WPT-Memory-Analysis-Heap) a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Alex K. for recommending DebugDiag which had been a huge help as you can see in the screenshot:

[image: DebugDiag-output]

We use WPF's WebBrowser (which is implemented by using an ActiveX control) to display a web page which runs a lot java script code.

Answer (score 2):

> Because of the fact that the heap is fine and the private bytes are directly allocated with VirtualAlloc() I can exclude 'our' managed application code from the list of possible leak candidates.

You see an increase of 1.5 GB in `<unknown>`, which is memory allocated via `VirtualAlloc()`. This can be memory of MSXML, any direct ("native") call of the function or of .NET which has its own heap manager (and thus not falls into the `Heap` category, which is the C++ heap).

Since you have a .NET application, it's probably .NET code which is responsible for those 1.5 GB of lost memory.

If you only have the dumps, you can load [sos](/questions/tagged/sos) with `.loadby sos clr` and use `!dumpheap -stat` to see where your memory is. The output will list the number of objects and total size per class.

The memory might be already freed from .NET's point of view, so it's listed as `Free`. You may also want to make sure that a garbage collection has happened, otherwise there may be false positives.

A crash dump only shows you the memory at a certain point in time. The various ways of analyzing this with specialized memory leak tools have the benefit that they will track the stack traces of allocations and give a better insight on what happens over time.

Comment: So MSXML calls `VirtualAlloc()` directly?

Comment: @MarcSherman: at least the last time I had problems with it. Must have been ~2009 and was probably MSXML 6.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue once at work, we solved it by using JetBrains Memory Profiler called dotMemory, it shows you exactly where the memory leak is.

I believe they have a 30 days trial periode.

https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/features/

Comment: @thomai: are you sure? Did you read my answer and were you able to make any progress?